# App não roda em outros celulares

Tags: android

Desenvolvi alguns apps que rodaram tranquilamente no meu celular, mas quando instalo em outro só da a mensagem de que o app parou e essa mensagem de erro no Android Studio.

```
05-17 09:03:55.571 15862-15862/com.example.roma0x.heitorapp E/AndroidRuntime:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.roma0x.heitorapp, PID: 15862
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageButton
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
at com.example.roma0x.heitorapp.Fragmentos.BichosFragment.onCreateView(BichosFragment.java:30)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2199)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1236)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1084)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:400)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3111)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20214)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2683)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1636)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1928)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1524)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7520)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:622)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.ja
```

XML-Fagmento Bichos: Estou fazendo um app pro meu sobrinho aprender a falar

Comment: Em que pasta a imagem do ImageButton da fragment BichosFragment está?

Comment: verifique se a imagem está na pasta "drawable"

Comment: exatamente está na drawable

Comment: Por favor envie o xml dessa fragment

Comment: só da comprimento excedido quando colo aqui...

Comment: Evite colocar esse tipo de coisa nos comentários, edite a pergunta :D

Comment: consegue visualizar a xml agora?

Answer (score 1):

O motivo do erro era onde as imagens estavam sendo salvas a minha drawable estava salvando as imagens dentro de uma pasta chamada drawable-v24 que estava dentro da drawable, só troquei as imagens de pasta e o app rodou normalmente em outros celulares.

Answer (score 0):

No Android Studio tem uma função de gerar o arquivo apk para ser instalador e tem outra função para compilar e executar, são duas rotinas separadas mas as duas geram um apk, e a de compilar gera um apk incompleto.

Vá em `Build\Builds APK`, essa rotina sim gera o instalador.
As Rotinas `Run`, `Make`, `Debug` geram os apk incompleto, uma versão para ser executada direto no emulador ou do cabo USB.

Comment: o erro continua acontecendo, em pesquisa vi que pode ser problema com as imagens

Comment: ok então. Comigo ja aconteceu parecido.

Comment: como eu imaginava, quando retiro as imagens o app roda, logo cheguei a conclusão que o problema é com a adaptação da imagem em outros smartphones, alguém sabe a solução para esse problema?

Comment: Qual o formato das imagens? Em que pasta estão? Qual a versão do android dos outros celulares?

Comment: O motivo do erro era onde as imagens estavam sendo salvas a minha drawable estava salvando as imagens dentro de uma pasta chamada drawable-v24 que estava dentro da drawable, só troquei as imagens de pasta e o app rodou normalmente em outros celulares.

Comment: esse sufixo de pasta -v24 deve ser usado se voce quiser que a imagem seja diferente nas versoes acima do android 24, seria para imagens diferente a cada versao, tembem serve para layout